# Application on key as home button

Tags: vba, excel, button

I'm collecting measurements in an Excel workbook.
All the measurements are displayed in separate sheets.
The average and max of every sheets'  measurement is displayed in the home sheet (with the name "1")

I added a line of code to jump from the home sheet to a certain sheet by entering the sheet name in cell J23 and clicking on a button.

Now i'd like to add a physical key/button in order to go back to the home sheet.
for example with ctrl+b

unfortunately my code does not work yet.
I've pasted my code below, hope someone has a solution.
Thanks in advance

```
Sub Macro1()

i = Sheets("1").Range("J23").Value

    Worksheets(i).Select

End Sub

Sub Home()

Application.OnKey "^b", Worksheets("1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `Application.OnKey` the name of a procedure, not a VBA command as you are trying to do.

Something along these lines:

```
Sub Home()
    Sheets(1).Select
End Sub

Sub SetUp()
    Application.OnKey "^b", "Home"
End Sub
```

The above subs are in a standard code module. When I run `SetUp`, I am afterwards able to get back to Sheet1 from any other sheet by entering `Ctrl+b`.